# My terminal dies when I use commands like dmesg, ls -la, history, sudo apt-get update

Tags: bash

So I was working on something today, needed to use online banking, and the bank asked me to install a security module, refusing to let me bank without it. The annoying thing is that the standard Ubuntu install did not work my 14.04 LTS due to dependency versions, so I tried the other distros install. Here's the link of instructions I followed (not too good of any idea of what's inside warsaw.run): https://seg.bb.com.br/duvidas.html?question=6#en

I can't say for sure this caused my problem, but my shell terminal quits abruptly when I run dmesg, history, ls -la, sudo apt-get update, ls /usr/bin and probably others.

I have no idea how to even diagnose this! I can run these commands just fine from a tty1, and my PATH seems to be intact. How can I discover more about the problem to fix it? I'd rather not reinstall, as I've got tons of work I need to finish.

stat /tmp

```
controlfreak ~ $ stat /tmp
  File: ‘/tmp’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 807h/2055d      Inode: 14811137    Links: 6
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-03-08 21:58:28.233840725 -0300
Modify: 2017-03-08 22:17:01.273853887 -0300
Change: 2017-03-08 22:17:01.273853887 -0300
 Birth: -
```

error messages upon crashing gnome-terminal that was opened from xterm:

```
controlfreak ~ $ gnome-terminal

(gnome-terminal:7062): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.

**Vte-2.90:ERROR:/build/vte3-dpQaUV/vte3-0.34.9/./src/vtestream-file.h:319:_file_write: assertion failed: (_file_isopen (f) || !len)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I know it's the default terminal that comes with Ubuntu Unity, from what I see here in the software center, it could be either xterm or gnome-terminal. I believe it's gnome-terminal from comparing the icons

Comment: It's probably gnome-terminal that you're using now. Does this also happen in xterm? It's also installed by default.

Comment: it's gnome-terminal! I can open xterm from it and xterm is different. another thing I just noticed: I ran gnome-terminal from inside a gnome-terminal and then when I used ls -la it killed both gnome-terminals, but left xterm running. also xterm does not seem to be affected, so I will attempt to purge and reinstall gnome-terminal

Comment: I just apt-get purged, apt-get autoremoved, apt-get autocleaned, and apt-get installed gnome-terminal. I ran gnome-terminal again and it still dies with ls -la

Comment: Probably a bug. In xterm, what does `stat /tmp` report? Also, open gnome-terminal from xterm and make it crash. Add the output and errors to the your question, please.

Comment: added those, but I believe the first part of the error message showed up immediately after starting gnome-terminal, only the ** Vte-2.90 is part of the error message

Comment: Do `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`. Your `/tmp` has incorrect permissions.

Comment: awesome! Thanks!! that fixed it! in addition, I was now able to search the error message and find an old thread with the same solution.

Comment: one question though, is there a log where I can find out when /tmp's permissions were change or what caused the change?

Comment: Probably look for `chmod` in your bash history `grep chmod ~/.bash_history`. It wasn't the package, best I can tell. Whoever made the package is certainly dumb, but they didn't touch `/tmp`.

Comment: weird, i can't find anything in history, and last I recall it's set to infinite. and I have no reason to ever type /tmp into a terminal. the only other thing I was doing at the time was running a jupyter notebook on floydhub's GPU servers. they've got a funky cli, but I'm not sure that would have done it... :/

I really appreciate your help mate! If you were in Florianopolis, Brazil, I'd buy you a beer!

Comment: anything I should do to mark this question resolved?

Comment: No, I closed this question as a duplicate of another, so you don't need to do anything further.